# What do the indices of the 2nd-level array returned by getMatchingProductIds() represent?

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I'm trying to get the products that are matched by a certain Catalog Price Rule (ID: 1) by using `getMatchingProductIds()`. The function returns **all** products, with their IDs as indices of the 1st level array. The second level array will have values either 0 or 1 depending on whether that product matches the Catalog Price Rule.

For example, my code:

```
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1)->getMatchingProductIds();
```

returns something like:

```
Array (

    [1348] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [4] => 1
    )
)
```

where 1348 is a product ID.

What do the indices in the 2nd level array (0, 1, 2, 4) represent? Why are there 4 of them? Why does it skip 3? Can their values NOT be all "1" even if the product matches the Catalog Price Rule?

(I do know that since they are all equal to 1, it means the product matches the Catalog Price Rule. But I don't know why there are 4 elements in that array, and what the indices mean.)

**EDIT**

My rule:

- Status - Active
- Websites - 3/3 selected (main website, example1.com, example2.com)
- Customer Groups - 4/4 selected (not logged in, general, wholesale, retailer)
- From Date - 1/10/13
- To Date - 9/12/13
- Priority - 1
- Conditions - if any of the conditions are true: category is 160
- Apply - To Fixed Amount
- Discount Amount - 10
- Enable Discounts to Subproducts - No
- Stop Further Rules Processing - No
- Related Banners - none

Comment: Maybe you should add your rule in the question. I only get an array of product ids. Just one level.

Comment: Hi @Marius, I added the rule.

Comment: Strange. I still get the same result. A one dimension array with product ids.

Comment: @Marius are you using catalogrule or the enterpise targetrule as that will return a different format. Not sure what the target rule is used for though.

Comment: @DavidManners I tested with CE 1.7 (so no target rule) and I only had one single website. Maybe that's why I was getting a different result

Comment: @Marius maybe I just noticed that the target rule returns the array in the format you were getting :)

Comment: @Marius found it version 1.7 has a different callback function

Comment: @DavidManners. I saw you answer. Already +1'd it :). A also saw your update. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

The indices on the second level are the website id. It appears to loop through each website and checks if that product and rule combination is valid for that website.

The function that does this is the callback from the results walk.

```
/**
 * Callback function for product matching
 *
 * @param $args
 * @return void
 */
public function callbackValidateProduct($args)
{
    $product = clone $args['product'];
    $product->setData($args['row']);

    $results = array();
    foreach ($this->_getWebsitesMap() as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
        $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
        $results[$websiteId] = (int)$this->getConditions()->validate($product);
    }
    $this->_productIds[$product->getId()] = $results;
}
```

So that array is of format.

```
Array (
    [product_id] => Array (
        [website_id] => is_valid,
    )
)
```

**NOTE:** In older versions of Magento this was not the case. It used to just return an array or productIds. Versions before 1.8 had the following code.

```
/**
 * Callback function for product matching
 *
 * @param $args
 * @return void
 */
public function callbackValidateProduct($args)
{
    $product = clone $args['product'];
    $product->setData($args['row']);

    if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
        $this->_productIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
```